# Ambiguous tag: business-objects

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

The tag [business-objects](/questions/tagged/business-objects) is currently being used for both

- The SAP Business Intelligence suite
- The business logic layer in an object oriented application

I'd imagine that sap-business-objects for the former case would be the logical change. How would this be requested, or should I simply unilaterally make this change (which doesn't sound quite right).

Answer (score 2):

[business-object](/questions/tagged/business-object) is synonymous to [domain-object](/questions/tagged/domain-object). Both are widely used. Even wikipedia redirects to Business Object article if yo visit [Domain Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_object). So we need a synonym tag.

Moreover, * SAP Business Intelligence* can not hold a generic term like that. It should be renamed to [sap-business-objects](/questions/tagged/sap-business-objects)